# Best way to implement a dynamic attendance recorder from multiple sources

Tags: c#

Good day friends,

Needs some advice regarding following implementation:

We have an in house developed application that gets data from Biometric Device and Bar Code scanner to record attendance, at the moment the implementation is not dynamic and if a new recording mechanism say e.g. RFID is introduced we will have to develop that code.

I want to make it dynamic such that these various input methods are treated as Channels.

My question is how can I implement it such that data from each device is automatically recorded. There can be two implementations (i guess)

1. Develop (code) separate capturing mechanism for each recorder. --> No issue with this implementation.
2. Develop (code) generic recorder. --> Is this possible? if so, how to implement it?

Thanks and Regards,
Saqib

Comment: SO is meant for specific technical problems and is not suited for broad application design advice. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Again, please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: You still need to implement the code that handles driver messages from concrete device, every time that device changes. It can be same manufacturer, different version of device, it can be different manufacturer, it can be you need to handle more features as by request, and so on... There is no way you can avoid that and make it generic. Not sure what you mean by "recorder" though.

Comment: Hi Igor, okay thanks will try to keep that in mind, but i though that SO members can help in giving ideas or for brainstorming, Since I did not ask for code of any sort just advice.

Comment: Hi Tigran, please put your answer in reply to mark as accepted, because on further thinking I agree. By recorder I meant a collector. I guess it will be better if I develop the application such that it exposes a function that can be used by recorder to add data against specific channel. also i will have to see how I will implement the registration part of the collectors.